# Including bean definition when a profile is NOT active

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles, negation

In my application I use several [profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) to make certain beans eligible for autowiring. What I'm missing is the possibility to make a bean eligible for autowiring when a certain profile is NOT active.

The best way of doing it that I thought about is like this:

1. Let's suppose we have a list of all possible profiles, e.g. {A, B, C, D}.
2. Profiles active for particular execution are {A, C}.
3. What I do is I create artificial profiles for all possible profiles which are not active. In the example case I would create {not_B, not_D} profiles.
4. The beans I want to be active based on not active profile `X` I make active for profile `not_X`. In my case if I wanted a bean to be eligible for autowiring when profile B is not active, I would annotate them `@Profile("not_B")`

This solution however requires an up-front knowledge about all possible profiles.

Can you think of any better solution?

Answer (score 116):

You can use a not (!) operator... but you have to use Spring 3.2 M1.

> The following syntax is now supported
>
> ```
> <beans profile="A,!B">
>
> @Profile({"A", "!B"})
> ```
>
> indicating that the  element or annotated component should be processed only if profile 'A' is active or profile 'B' is not active.

See change announced here: [Spring Framework 3.2 M1 Released](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/29/spring-framework-3-2-m1-released)
The commit is at GitHub: [Support not (!) operator for profile selection](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/commit/bcd44f3798ed06c0704d2a3564b8a9735e747e87)
Issue in JIRA: [SPR-8728](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8728)

If upgrading to Spring 3.2 is not possible for your project, I would recommend not using the `@Profile` approach and ensuring that the bean is not created in your Spring configuration.

Comment: This would be great, but Spring 3.2 is in RC1 right now, so it's not an option for me.

Comment: See my change to the post.  I would recommend not initialising with @Profile then and handle this in Spring configuration.

Comment: @Shyj Thought about that too (like configuring the classpath scanner with exclusion), but that just doesn't seem as nice as profiles...

Comment: @Shyj I absolutely agree... but the exclusion on your classpath scan is likely your best option if you are pinned to 3.1.

Comment: @MarcoFerrari OP ([ShyJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815355/shyj)) last seen Dec 21 '12 at 22:19. No matter how good this answer is, it's never gonna be accepted. =(

Comment: I was wondering whether we can do a 
@Profile("!default", "!test")