# How to selectively disable Eureka discovery client with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Is there a way to disable spring-boot eureka client registration based on the spring profile?

Currently I use the following annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer

public class ConfigApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

What I need is either a conditional such as (excuse the pseudo code)

```
@if (Profile!="development")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@endif
```

Or some way in the application properties file. I have tried setting application.yml file as:

```
spring:
  profiles: development
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: false
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including bean definition when a profile is NOT active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575201/including-bean-definition-when-a-profile-is-not-active)

Comment: To use class in all cases excluding one profile, you can write `@Profile("!development")`

Comment: Trying to track down where in the docs that "!development" syntax is outlined ... so far without any luck.@dmitryvim

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do it like this: create some `@Configuration` annotated class (class body can be omitted) ex.:

```
@Profile("!development")
@Configuration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class EurekaClientConfiguration {
}
```

It means that this configuration file (and `@EnableDiscoveryClient` within) will be loaded in every profile except "developement".

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for

Comment: Upvoting this because it's an awesome answer.

Comment: People who use SO tend to copy code right away. Please fix "developement".wasted my whole hour.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for that. I know how big pain in the ass is looking for something like that.

Comment: It works but stil issue occur when running the tests .

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to avoid this while running test! Thank you @EnricoGiurin for putting this - else I was thinking this solution isn't working.

Comment: Using profile depending settings is technically fine but poor because it degrades the quality of your production code.

Answer (score 106):

You can disable eureka client in application.yml using this:

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

It's also for one profile

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: in application.yml or application.properties you can set spring variables in different profiles, as it was written in third question code sample. I just suggested to disable eureka this way

Comment: To disable the Eureka Discovery Client, you can set eureka.client.enabled to false. Eureka Discovery Client will also be disabled when spring.cloud.discovery.enabled is set to false. Check Link https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_registering_with_eureka

Comment: @KaranKaw `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled` is incorrect. The correct property name is `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled`, and setting that to `false` fixed my issue.

Comment: @KaranKaw @Raphael actually, `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled: false` worked well for me, whereas `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: false` did not.  I'm using spring-boot 2.7.12 + spring-core 5.3.30 + spring-cloud-starter-* 3.1.1, in case it could be related with some flagging difference.

Answer (score 21):

With the latest version of Spring Cloud Finchley.SR2 if you are using the annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient you have to set all of the following properties in application.properties to disable the service registration:

```
spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled=false
eureka.client.enabled=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.registerWithEureka=false
```

Answer (score 11):

Same issue here. You can simply put in your application property file the following configuration:

```
  spring:
    profiles: development

  eureka:
    instance:
      hostname: localhost
    client:
      registerWithEureka: false
      fetchRegistry: false
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a standard boolean spring-cloud property

spring.cloud.discovery.enabled

This might be better than "eureka" specific since you might be using a different provider.

Comment: In my case this doesn't work but `eureka.client.enabled: false` does.

Answer (score 6):

With the latest version of Spring boot, Please add this in the bootstrap.yml file

Spring cloud version : Edgeware: SR3 and above

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
  cloud:
    service-registry:
      auto-registration:
        enabled: false
```

This will disable eureka. To enable it, we just need to make enabled as true

Answer (score 4):

> To disable the Eureka Discovery Client, you can set
> `eureka.client.enabled` to `false`.
> Eureka Discovery Client will also be
> disabled when `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled` is set to `false`.

Reference 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_registering_with_eureka

Comment: `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled: false` worked well for me. Thank you @KaranKaw