# Spring Boot @EnableEurekaClient conditionally

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm using several profiles for my app, that I can select via the application.yml prop:

```
spring.profiles.active: dev #can be integration, uat, prod
```

My applications all start by:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MyApp {
}
```

Now, I'd like to enable the eureka client only for selected profiles. I don't want, for example, to enable that in dev profile as in dev you don't mind about the service register right?

Is it possible? I tried to move eureka related properties in the single profile files but they are found anyway...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eureka discovery client - selective disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142105/eureka-discovery-client-selective-disable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can extract your config and only activate it on certain profiles

```
@Configuration
@Profile(value= {"uat","prod"})
@EnableEurekaClient
public class EurekaClientConfiguration {
   //your configuration
}
```

on the other hand you could de-activate config for a certain profile by using a **!** (=not) `@Profile("!dev")`