# Failed to bind properties under 'eureka.client.enabled' to boolean

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

why is the new `spring-cloud-config` so complicated?

I would like to do the following: enable eureka on default and add it in some profiles (not in all).
no matter in which way I tried it, it didn't work.
I get this error `Failed to bind properties under 'eureka.client.enabled' to boolean`.

first way:

```
server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false # default disabled
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: 127.0.0.1

spring:
  application:
    name: app
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: config-server
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 5

application:
  value: app-default

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

application:
  value: app-dev

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: qa
    import: "configserver:"
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true # enable it in profile "qa"
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/

application:
  value: app-qa
```

second way:

```
server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true # default enabled
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: 127.0.0.1

spring:
  application:
    name: app
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: config-server
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 5

application:
  value: app-default

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false # disable in profile "dev"

application:
  value: app-dev

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: qa
    import: "configserver:"
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/ # I also need a profile specific url

application:
  value: app-qa
```

if I activate eureka once and never use `eureka.client.enabled` again, then the error with the url occurs: `Failed to bind properties under 'eureka.client.serviceUrl. defaultZone' to String` - but I need this profile specific url in any case!

all this has to do with the new `spring-cloud-config`. because after I deleted all the lines for the config-server and commented out the `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency, both variants with eureka worked!
or do i have an error according to this `spring-cloud-config` stuff?

versions:

```
    <spring-boot.version>2.5.2</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: Looking for a way to disable eureka client registration based on profile?

Comment: yes exactly. with the "old" config server the works fine. but with the new one not

Comment: What version of spring cloud are you using?

Comment: I added them in the initial post. but I mean the `import: "configserver:"` indicates a very new version

Comment: Are you using the `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation? I think the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142105/how-to-selectively-disable-eureka-discovery-client-with-spring) can help you.

Comment: that is not the problem. in your post there is also a hint for `eureka.client.enabled = false`. I have narrowed it down further that I need also a `default` profile on my default values on top of the file. then the application starts. but the values from the config server are not invoked...

Comment: Is your problem that your application does not start with your values in config-server?

Comment: after long researches and tests -> my problem now is: I can't provide multiple eureka urls in one application.yml file (for different profiles)